# Finding right type class to use

Tags: scala, playframework, typeclass

I'm trying to implement a type class solution for error handling in a Play application. What I want is to have some type class instances representing some validated (caught) errors and a default type class instance for any unvalidated (uncaught) errors.

I don't know if this is possible, but here's what I have so far:

```
trait ResponseError[E] {
  def report(e: E)(implicit logger: Logger): Unit
  def materialize(e: E): Result
}

trait ValidatedError[E <: Throwable] extends ResponseError[E] {
  def report(e: E)(implicit logger: Logger): Unit =
    ResponseError.logError(e)
}

trait UnvalidatedError[E <: Throwable] extends ResponseError[E] {
  def report(e: E)(implicit logger: Logger): Unit = {
    ResponseError.logError(e)
    UnvalidatedError.notify(e)
  }
}

object ResponseError {
  def logError(e: Throwable)(implicit logger: Logger): Unit =
    logger.error(e.getMessage)
}

object ValidatedError {
  import java.util.concurrent.{ExecutionException, TimeoutException}

  implicit val executionError = new ValidatedError[ExecutionException] {
    def materialize(e: E): Result =
      play.api.mvc.Results.BadRequest
  }

  implicit val timeoutError   = new ValidatedError[TimeoutException] {
    def materialize(e: E): Result =
      play.api.mvc.Results.RequestTimeout
  }
}

object UnvalidatedError {

  implicit uncaughtError = new UnvalidatedError[Throwable] {
    def materialize(e: E): Result =
      play.api.mvc.Results.ServiceUnavailable
  }

  private def notify(e: Throwable) = ??? // send email notification
}
```

However how can I make sure to try my `ValidatedError` type class instances first, before falling back to my `UnvalidatedError` type class instance?

Comment: Could you extend your question with how you are intending to use it?

Comment: If you make the ValidatedError extend the UnvalidatedError, the implicits should get resolved correctly with Validated being higher priority. The type of the exception must be known at compile time though, or it will be treated as a Throwable regardless. Remember to use scala.control.NonFatal instead of catching all Throwables!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go. See my comment for details.

```
  import java.util.concurrent.{TimeoutException, ExecutionException}

  type Result = String

  val badRequest: Result = "BadRequest"
  val requestTimeout: Result = "RequestTimeout"
  val serviceUnavailable: Result = "ServiceUnavailable"

  class Logger {
    def error(s: String) = println(s + "\n")
  }

  trait ResponseError[E] {
    def report(e: E)(implicit logger: Logger): Unit
    def materialize(e: E): Result
  }

  trait ValidatedError[E <: Throwable] extends UnvalidatedError[E] {
    override def report(e: E)(implicit logger: Logger): Unit =
      ResponseError.logError(e, validated = true)
  }

  trait UnvalidatedError[E <: Throwable] extends ResponseError[E] {
    def report(e: E)(implicit logger: Logger): Unit = {
      ResponseError.logError(e, validated = false)
      UnvalidatedError.notify(e)
    }
  }

  object ResponseError {
    def logError(e: Throwable, validated: Boolean)(implicit logger: Logger): Unit =
      logger.error({
        validated match {
          case true => "VALIDATED : "
          case false => "UNVALIDATED : "
        }
      } + e.getMessage)
  }

  object ValidatedError {
    import java.util.concurrent.{ExecutionException, TimeoutException}

    implicit def executionError[E <: ExecutionException] = new ValidatedError[E] {
      def materialize(e: E): Result =
        badRequest
    }

    implicit def timeoutError[E <: TimeoutException]  = new ValidatedError[E] {
      def materialize(e: E): Result =
        requestTimeout
    }
  }

  object UnvalidatedError {

    implicit def uncaughtError[E <: Throwable] = new UnvalidatedError[E] {
      def materialize(e: E): Result =
        serviceUnavailable
    }

    private def notify(e: Throwable) = println("Sending email: " + e) // send email notification
  }

  def testTypeclass[E](e: E)(implicit logger: Logger, ev: ResponseError[E]): Unit ={
    ev.report(e)

  }

  import ValidatedError._
  import UnvalidatedError._

  implicit val logger: Logger = new Logger

  val executionErr = new ExecutionException(new Throwable("execution exception!"))

  testTypeclass(executionErr)

  val timeoutErr = new TimeoutException("timeout exception!")

  testTypeclass(timeoutErr)

  val otherErr = new Exception("other exception!")

  testTypeclass(otherErr)
```

Output:

```
  VALIDATED : java.lang.Throwable: execution exception!

  VALIDATED : timeout exception!

  UNVALIDATED : other exception!

  Sending email: java.lang.Exception: other exception!
```